# Split data for circular buffer in C

Tags: split, circular-buffer

I am writing code for circular buffer in C but am stuck at writing input to buffer when the write wraps up.

I take a block of data as input from user which includes number, string, Null character, anything and write it into the buffer. When the write pointer reaches the end of the pointer, it wraps to the top and starts writing data from there. So to do this, I want to split the block data so that half data will be written at the bottom of the write pointer and remaining data will be written from the top.

I am not able to split that data. Any method to do this ?

EDIT: Code I am using to write the data.

```
if (length > circular_buffer_available_space_bottom(cb)) {

/* copy data in the buffer till the end */
memcpy(circular_buffer_ends_at(cb), data, space_bottom);
/* Move the rear pointer to the next write location */
cb->rear = (cb->rear + space_bottom) % cb->length;

/* Calculate space available at top of the buffer */
space_top = length - space_bottom;

/* copy remaining data in available space at the top  */
memcpy(circular_buffer_ends_at(cb), data,space_top);

/* Move the rear pointer to the next write location */
cb->rear = (cb->rear + space_top) % cb->length;
}
```

Here, first the length of the input data is checked.
So when the data is written at bottom, it should be splitted and the remaining data needs to be written at top which is in second memcpy().

Right now, I haven't splitted that data and I am searching for a way to split it.
This code would give me error as the space available will be less than required.

Comment: what language are you using? how are blocks implemented? without this information it is impossible to answer this question

Comment: Suppose user writes block of 15 bytes in buffer sized 25 bytes.
Then he reades 5 bytes.
so Total available space to write = 10(bottom of write pointer) + 5(top of write pointer) = 15.
So If the user writes another 15 bytes then 10 bytes need to be written at bottom and then pointer wraps to the top and remaining data is written on top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what is the problem with splitting the data?

Answer (score 0):

A circular buffer with a fixed size comes down to a `queue`.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) offers a good explanation with code examples in C.

Comment: But the codes given and the explanation is for single element input. Here, I have strings, numbers, Null character as input so its kind of block of data.

Comment: Then first convert everything that is going to be written to the buffer to a byte array. You will also need a way to convert it back into the original datatypes after reading from the buffer. Since it seems you want to store different datatypes in the same buffer, perhaps you need to look at serializing/deserializing the  data first.